# Is there a way to pass the returning value of a method as a prop to a Vue component?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, nuxt.js

I have a Vue.js component (named `<dynamic-input/>`) which accepts a prop (called `input`). I'm trying to pass the returning value of a method (named `normalizeInput`) which is defined in the parent component:

### template

```vue
<div v-for="input in inputList" :key="input.id">
    <dynamic-input :input="normalizeInput(input)" />
</div>
```

### script

```vue
methods: {
    normalizeInput(input) {
        //do something with input
        return normalizedInput;
    }
}
```

Apparently this doesn't work; Is there a way to achieve this? Am I Doing Something Wrong?

I'm Using nuxt v2.15.7

Comment: You should post what is in your "//do something with input" because if you didn't define "normalizedInput" you are returning nothing. Otherwise this should work... Maybe post your "dynamic-input" component as well and your errors... You can give default values to props inside your "dynamic-input". You can use computed properties as said in the answer from @Boussadjra Brahim if only that is your problem. There is more ways how to do this.

Comment: @digitalniweb Thankyou for your help, this was working but the value that it returned wasn't correct; I've fixed that and the problem was fixed. Using computed properties worked too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've to use a computed property that returns a function with the input as parameters :

```vue
computed: {
    normalizeInput() {
        
        return (input) =>{
            return normalizedInput;
        } 
    }
}
```